# remove cookies from Zf2 Controller

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am trying to remove cookies from my controller `UserController` for `ZfcUser` Module.

When the user logs out, I want to delete all cookies.

For example, I am setting cookies in the view:

```
setcookie("var", $value);
```

LogoutAction :

```
 public function logoutAction()
    {

        $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthAdapter()->resetAdapters();
        $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthAdapter()->logoutAdapters();
        $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getAuthService()->clearIdentity();

        $redirect = $this->params()->fromPost('redirect', $this->params()->fromQuery('redirect', false));

        if ($this->getOptions()->getUseRedirectParameterIfPresent() && $redirect) {


            return $this->redirect()->toUrl($redirect);
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->getOptions()->getLogoutRedirectRoute());
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem you encountred ? And what's your question ?

Comment: i need some code to delete stored cookies by name somthing like remove('cookies_names'); 
or any other code from my LogoutAction method in the controller

Comment: Did you try with `Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to delete or create a cookie with zend framework 2 classes use the `Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie` class and inject the instance into the response header

**Create a cookie**

```
// create a cookie
$cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie(
    'testcookie',
    'testData',
    strtotime('+1 Year', time()), // 1 year lifetime
    '/'
);

$this->getServiceManager()->get('Response')->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
```

**Delete a cookie**

to delete a cookie over zend the same rule apply as delete a cookie over the php `setcookie` function - just place the same cookie name with a negative `lifetime` and inject it into the response header - just like create a cookie as above

```
// cookie löschen
$cookie = new \Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie(
    'testcookie',
    '',
    strtotime('-1 Year', time()), // -1 year lifetime (negative from now)
    '/'
);
$this->getServiceManager()->get('Response')->getHeaders()->addHeader($cookie);
```

Comment: `time()` is assumed as default value of `strtotime` second parameter and can be safely omitted.

Comment: the second param is set because this is more "readable" for less informed users that a year is subtracted from the current time

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework 2 permits to store cookies in the HTTP request, so you can access theme in the  headers using the [Zend\Http\Header\SetCookie](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Header/SetCookie.php) class.

Here is an example of setting and removing cookies with this mecanisme :

```
$cookie = new SetCookie('name', 'value');
$cookie->setExpires(time() + 365 * 60 * 60 * 24);
$headers= $this->getResponse()->getHeaders();
$headers->addHeader($cookie);
```

**Remove a cookie by name :**
Before removing a cookie, you may check whether it is present in the request or not. This is a simple code to do that :

```
public function logoutAction()
{
 //.....

$cookie= $this->getRequest()->getCookie();
if ($cookie->offsetExists('name')) {
$new_cookie= new SetCookie('name', '');//<---empty value and the same 'name'
$new_cookie->setExpires(-(time() + 365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
$headers->addHeader($new_cookie);

//.....
}
```